# Understanding Client Side Rendering and Server Side Rendering in a full-stack-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, client-side, server-side-rendering

This question might seem novice, but I really want to know as I've read numerous articles without some really effective examples.

So I have a full-stack application where I am using express and mongo for the backend and React, Redux for the frontend. I am not sure if this is SSR or CSR. In my application, I have configured Webpack and not used Create-React-App.

To start the build process, I run `npm start` and the code compiles successfully. But is it CSR or SSR?

Comment: Does your backend return HTML pages? Then it's SSR. Or does your backend only return data via AJAX and it's assembled into pages in the browser in React? Then it's CSR.

Comment: Yes. the app fetches data making AJAX calls to the database, then through react and redux displays the pages to the browser. So, I'm using webpack and it returns a single bundle of code. How does webpack fit in all this? Also, if I use something like `ejs` templating engine in a simple node app(without frontend tech), it's SSR, right?

Comment: Webpack just compiles your various Javascript files into one Javascript bundle/compiles Typescript/does all sorts of stuff to turn highly advanced Javascript syntax and tooling into something that can be executed in the browser. Ultimately it just makes your Javascript ready for the browser, it doesn't fundamentally change where the rendering is happening. If you had a Node app which outputs HTML via a template engine, that'd be SSR, yes.